FbLoginManager.loginwithPermissions was called with 1 arguments butt expects 3 arguments
enter image description here
I'm using react-native-fbsdk-next version ^12.1.0, and I want it to redirect to Facebook for login.
I am using RCTLinkingManager to handle URL opening in my AppDelegate.m file:
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {
    if ([[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:app openURL:url options:options]) {
        return YES;
    }

    if ([RCTLinkingManager application:app openURL:url options:options]) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
`const result = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions([
    'public_profile',
    'email',
]);

if (result.isCancelled) {
    throw 'User cancelled the login process';
}

// Once signed in, get the user's AccessToken
const data = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

if (!data) {
    throw 'Something went wrong obtaining access token';
}

